# What is this called "var count:Int { return items.count }" in Swift?

Tags: syntax, swift

I saw this code in the apple documentation for Swift:

```
var count:Int {
    return items.count
}
```

I thought that it could be a closure. The reason I believe it isn't is because it does not have an equals sign. So it is not assigning that variable to anything. If it is not a closure then what is it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a `Read-Only Computed Property`.

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_376):

> A computed property with a getter but no setter is known as a read-only computed property. A read-only computed property always returns a value, and can be accessed through dot syntax, but cannot be set to a different value.

Comment: A link more specific to the read-only computed property: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_331

Comment: Why yes it is a Read-Only Computed Property. Apparently I didn't do my reading thoroughly.